# What's the best way to have a grid of QWidget with fixed size column?

Tags: qt, qlayout

I am trying to build this QWidget with Qt :

1. | QLabel 00    |    QLabel 01                | QPushButton    |
2. | QLabel 10    |    QLabel 11                | (Nothing here) |
3. | QLabel 20    |    QLabel 21                | (Nothing here) |

Currently I have done it with a QGridLayout, the thing is I want the first and last column with a fixed width and QGridLayout doesn't have this feature. Indeed the first and last columns expand depending on QLabels 01, 11 and 21 size.

Is there a best way to have a fixed witdh on a specific column or did I miss something on the QGridLayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`QGridLayout::setColumnStretch`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch)...

```
my_grid_layout.setColumnStretch(0, 0);
my_grid_layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1);
my_grid_layout.setColumnStretch(2, 0);
```

The above should cause the grid layout to associate all *extra* width with column 1.